# Reuse DTO mappings across both single and list variants

Tags: entity-framework, linq, orm

We regularily write extension methods like this that convert from Database objects to DTO objects for use elsewhere in our system.

As you can see in the example below, the actual mapping code is repeated.  Is it possible to write a reusable select mapping that can be used in both of these methods?

```
    public static async Task<List<Group>> ToCommonListAsync(this IQueryable<DataLayer.Models.Group> entityGroups)
    {
        var groups =
            await entityGroups.Select(
                g =>
                    new Group()
                    {
                        Id = g.Id,
                        AccountId = g.AccountId,
                        Name = g.Name,
                        ParentId = g.ParentId,
                        UserIds = g.GroupUserMappings.Select(d => d.UserId).ToList()
                    }).ToListAsync();

        return groups;
    }

    public static async Task<Group> ToCommonFirstAsync(this IQueryable<DataLayer.Models.Group> entityGroups)
    {
        var group =
            await entityGroups.Select(
                g =>
                    new Group()
                    {
                        Id = g.Id,
                        AccountId = g.AccountId,
                        Name = g.Name,
                        ParentId = g.ParentId,
                        UserIds = g.GroupUserMappings.Select(d => d.UserId).ToList()
                    }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return group;
    }
```

Comment: My first thought would be to recommend using automapper
[solving entity framework performance issues using automapper](https://codewithstyle.info/solving-entity-framework-performance-issues-automapper) or [efficient querying with linq using automapper and future queries EF+](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/11/efficient-querying-with-linq-automapper-and-future-queries/)

Another solution would be to use Dapper, and you can create a single query and then call it as a list or a single for one mapped dto class, but in this case you would´t be using linq so is outside this scope.

Comment: @ManuelMejias Thank you for the comment, we previously used AutoMapper but found writing the mapping ourselves far more performant even if it takes a little more manual effort. Since then we have ripped out as much of AutoMapper as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your mapping/projection code out into a variable like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private static readonly Expression<Func<DataLayer.Models.Group, Group>> Projection = g => 
        new Group
        {
            Id = g.Id,
            AccountId = g.AccountId,
            Name = g.Name,
            ParentId = g.ParentId,
            UserIds = g.GroupUserMappings.Select(d => d.UserId).ToList()
        };

    public static async Task<List<Group>> ToCommonListAsync(this IQueryable<DataLayer.Models.Group> entityGroups)
    {
        return await entityGroups.Select(Projection).ToListAsync();
    }

    public static async Task<Group> ToCommonFirstAsync(this IQueryable<DataLayer.Models.Group> entityGroups)
    {
        return await entityGroups.Select(Projection).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter this looks good, presumably this will ensure the correct columns are selected in the SQL Query and mapped accordingly with no intermediary object?

Comment: Yes, it will work the same as having the mapping expression inline; the provider should translate it into SQL so that everything happens in the database.